# Format code block or code lines in ChatGPT

Tags: formatting, format, codeblocks, openai-api, chatgpt-api

Is it possible to format a code block or a code line in chatgpt like he does? I asked him and it tells me to do it with 3 backticks at the beginning and at the end but it doesnt work

Here's what i tried:

```

// Formatted Code Block

```

According to ChatGPT it should show me:

```
// Formatted Code Block
```

But it shows me exaclty what i tried without the formatting.

Comment: duplicated: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/169461/how-can-i-format-code-properly-in-a-chatgpt-prompt